# Greek Letter font in formula

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold

I used the following package in latex `\usepackage{amsmath,amsbsy,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,amsfonts}` 
and the following equation the parameter `$\boldsymbol{\beta}$` but the bold font is not bold enough please see the picture attached

[image]

how can I have the symbol more bold like

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please tell us if you use any particular font packages to load Times Roman, Palatino, or some other font family other than the default (which is Computer Modern).

Answer (score 3):

Not really recommended... But If you don't like any other solution is a last possibility:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\fakeBold#1{\tikz[inner sep=0]%
\foreach\i in{-0.04,-0.03,...,0.04}%
\node[xshift=\i,yshift=-\i]at(0,0){$\boldsymbol{#1}$};%
}


\begin{document}

test

$\boldsymbol{\beta}$

\fakeBold{\beta}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**PS: See campa's comment too**

Comment: One may mention that `amsmath` itself provides a similar solution: `\pmb`.

Comment: Thanks for the info @campa... I have used that before without know that... But my logic says that somebody would have think about it too...

Answer (score 3):

When seen in context the boldness is distinguishable, in my opinion.

You could substitute your betas with the CB fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{altgreek}{LGR}{cmr}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{altgreek}{bold}{LGR}{cmr}{bx}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathord}{altgreek}{`b}

\begin{document}

$\alpha+\bm{\alpha}$

$\beta+\bm{\beta}$

$\gamma+\bm{\gamma}$

\end{document}
```

Note that `amsbsy` is deprecated and `bm` should be used instead (it aliases `\boldsymbol`, so your documents don't need to be changed apart from loading `bm` instead of `amsbsy`).

[image]

Here's a comparison, right the standard symbols.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is it the same symbol that you like?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[]{bm}
\begin{document}


$\boldsymbol{\beta}$


\end{document}
```